# How to create single variable in Python with two columns either as tuple or Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, twitter, tuples

I need to consolidate these two tweet datasets into a single variable. The variable needs to have two "columns," one for the text of the tweets, the other a binary indicator of the source (e.g. 0 for the first source, 1 for the second). I can use a list of tuples or a Pandas dataframe. I am brand new to coding, so I am not sure how to proceed. I understand that I could create two dictionaries and combine them, but not sure how to add the column that contains the binary indicator. This is where I am now:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
userNRA = api.get_user("NRA")
userCSGV = api.get_user("CSGV")

c_nra = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="NRA")
NRAtweet_store = []
for status in c_nra.items(500):
    NRAtweet_store.append(status.text)

c_csgv = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="CSGV")
CSGVtweet_store = []
for status in c_csgv.items(500):
    CSGVtweet_store.append(status.text)
```

Comment: Have you given it a shot?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than appending just the text, append the text and a flag:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
userNRA = api.get_user("NRA")
userCSGV = api.get_user("CSGV")

tweets = []

c_nra = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="NRA")
for status in c_nra.items(500):
    tweets.append((status.text, 0))

c_csgv = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="CSGV")
for status in c_csgv.items(500):
    tweets.append((status.text, 1))
```

This will leave you with one list of tuples, with the second entry in each tuple indicating the source of the first entry.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be as simple a that! I suspected that as a beginner, I was trying to make it harder than it is...Cheers!

Comment: @TVWood glad to help! There's a tick to the left of my answer, which you can click to mark this is as the correct answer for your question.